# Function does not deliver the desired values in python

Tags: function, python-3.x

I am trying to use both functions below:

```
def func1():

    print('blahblah') 
    func2()

def func2():
    check = 0
    while check < 1:

        first = input('Integer or pass ')
        if first == 'pass':
            first = 0
            func1()
            break
        else:
            first = int(first)

        second = input('Integer or pass')
        if second == 'pass':
            second = 0
            func1()
            break
        else:
            second = int(second)

        third = input('Integer or pass' )
        if third == 'pass':
            third = 0
            func1()
            break
        else:
            third = int(third)        
        check = 1
  return first, second, third
```

The func2 returns None instead of the inputs when once "pass" was entered. What am I doing wrong?

edit: the results should be 3 integers, no matter how many times 'pass' was entered.
After changing the indentation I get following error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'second' referenced before assignment (in case I start with pass)

For clarifcation: func2 asks for input, if input is "pass" then func1 is called. 
After the print func1 calls func2 again . This repeats until 3 integers are input. Their valus shall be returned in th end.

Comment: Bad indentation.  Try moving the last two lines out of the while loop.

Comment: What should the function return if one of the inputs is `pass`?

Comment: if you enter pass, it calls func1 which then calls func2 again from the start. in the end only the integers should be returned

Comment: the indentation leads to another error (see my comment to answer to @Jarvis below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. You need to move the last statement `return first, second, third` one tab before.

Comment: I did this but the I get: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'second' referenced before assignment (in case I start with pass)

Comment: @Al_Iskander : Declare variables `first`, `second`, and `third` outside your `while` loop.
`first, second, third = None, None, None`

Comment: this still does not work. If I enter 'pass', 4, 5, 6 the return is then (0, None, None). I really do not understand the issue. It all looks consistent...

Comment: I think I got it, replace all the `break` statements by `return func1()`, due to the recursion, also, change `func2()` to `return func2()` in the definition of your function `func1()`.

Comment: still does not lead to the desired output (which is the 3 integers).  So user has to input 3 integers in a row, if he uses pass, func1 is called and then func2 is called again. then the 3 inputs start all over. and if 3 integers have been input, the func2 delivers them as return.

Comment: Please find the code here : http://ideone.com/v8q7kD, it gives correct output to me.

Comment: I suppose your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as accepted, (and hopefully upvote it too :) ) @Al_Iskander

Comment: thank you @Jarvis, but it does not work. The output is still 'None'

Comment: How ?? Have you seen the code, Please check carefully again, I modified the link once before. @Al_Iskander

Comment: that was the issue. I had the wrong link first. great stuff. without your help I would not have figured this out (and honestly I still do not understand why my script does not work).

Comment: You need to return the values everytime, since you don't pass the arguments in the function, that's why it wasn't working earlier. I would be glad if you upvote the answer too. :) @Al_Iskander